# Hide UINavigationBar without losing Status Bar background

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm working on an app where we use the white status bar tint and a dark background for the navigationBar. There is one scene where we want the navigationBar hidden but it also takes away the background color for the status bar. Is there a simple solution to keep a dark background up with hiding the navigationBar at the same time?

My code to hide the navigation bar is:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

or in Swift:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
```

Comment: last sentence you mean keep a white background right?

Comment: @hasan83 no, it needs to be dark because we're using the light style.

Comment: got it. can you provide the code that you used to style your navigation bar. (code that you used to set the color)

Comment: do you have translucent YES or NO?

Comment: It's not translucent, but I could set it to be. Wouldn't that keep the frame though? We need the tableview to be right below the status bar.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are developing for iOS7+: The statusbar doesn' have any background color on its own. In fact, the reason you are seeing a dark background when the navigation bar is visible, is because it extends upwards underneath the statusbar. So if you want to keep the status bar background you can simply add a view with an appropriate background color to the current scene (viewController, window , etc.). Give it a frame of `UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarFrame`.

**-- UPDATE 1 --**

Sample code (Swift 3) Gives you a solid black status bar background:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  private let statusBarUnderlay = UIView()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    statusBarUnderlay.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    view.addSubview(statusBarUnderlay)
  }

  override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    statusBarUnderlay.frame = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
  }
}
```

**-- UPDATE 2 --**

While we're at it. The above code is not how you should lay out your views. Instead, subclass `UIView` and do your layout there. Then override `loadView` of your `UIViewController` subclass and return an instance of your custom view.

```
class View: UIView {
  private let statusBarUnderlay = UIView()

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    statusBarUnderlay.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    addSubview(statusBarUnderlay)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("Storyboards are incompatible with truth and beauty.")
  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    statusBarUnderlay.frame = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
  }
}
```

Comment: So this kind of worked. It created the view, but it positioned it directly below the status bar.

Comment: can you log the views frame? it should be {0, 0, screenWidth, 20} in portrait

Comment: If I use lldb to "po view.frame" I get this:
(origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 0, height = 0))

Comment: hm. this would mean the view isn't visible at all. With po through lldb, it really depends when you break and log. are you sure your view hierarchy has layoutSubviews called before logging the frame? additionally, you could po UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarFrame, this should not return CGRectZero... i've updated my answer

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. For some reason it was considering (0, 0) as the corner directly under the status bar. I set the y to -20 and it looks fine. Together we are one hell of a developer! =D Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: BTW what was weird was even though the h and w was showing as 0, it was actually set to 20 and screen's width. Friggin' lldb.

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to do was add a secondary view and set it to below the status bar like this:

```
-(void)viewForStatusBar {
    UIView *view = [UIView new];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];        
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -20, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 20);
}
```

Or in Swift:

```
func viewForStatusBar() {
        let view = UIView()
        self.view.addSubview(view)
        view.backgroundColor = .blackColor()
        view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -20, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 20)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the implementation of [LTNavigationBar](https://github.com/ltebean/LTNavigationBar)

I think it may help you with.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    if (offsetY > 0) {
        if (offsetY >= 44) {
            [self setNavigationBarTransformProgress:1];
        } else {
            [self setNavigationBarTransformProgress:(offsetY / 44)];
        }
    } else {
        [self setNavigationBarTransformProgress:0];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = [UIImage new];
    }
}

- (void)setNavigationBarTransformProgress:(CGFloat)progress
{
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation:(0, -44 * progress)];
}
```

It makes the navigation bar hidden and status bar have the same background color as navigation bar when scrolling the view.If you don't need scrolling, you can just call `[self setNavigationBarTransformProgress:1]`